# How can an effect find out the display size of the UIImageView it is attached to?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uiimageview

In Xamarin.Forms, an [`Effect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/) can be attached to a `View`. In my case, the View is displaying an `Image`. And the effect is making a colored "glow" around the visible pixels of the image. XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding LogoImage}" ...>
    <Image.Effects>
        <effects:GlowEffect Radius="5" Color="White" />
    </Image.Effects>
</Image>
```

The effect is implemented as a subclass of `RoutingEffect`:

```
public class GlowEffect : Xamarin.Forms.RoutingEffect
{
    public GlowEffect() : base("Core.ImageGlowEffect")
    {
    }
...
}
```

On each platform, there is a `PlatformEffect` to implement the effect. For iOS:

```
using ...

[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(Core.Effects.ImageGlowEffect), "ImageGlowEffect")]
namespace Core.Effects
{
  public class ImageGlowEffect : PlatformEffect
  {
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        ApplyGlow();
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged( PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged( e );

        if (e.PropertyName == "Source") {
            ApplyGlow();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyGlow()
    {
        var imageView = Control as UIImageView;
        if (imageView.Image == null)
            return;

        var effect = (GlowEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is GlowEffect);

        if (effect != null) {
            CGRect outSize = AVFoundation.AVUtilities.WithAspectRatio( new CGRect( new CGPoint(), imageView.Image.Size ), imageView.Frame.Size );
                ...
        }
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

The above code works if `Source` is changed dynamically: at the time `Source` changes, the `UIImageView` (`Bounds` or `Frame`) has a size. BUT if the Source is set statically in XAML, that logic does not run: so the only call to `ApplyGlow` is during `OnAttach`. UNFORTUNATELY, during `OnAttach`, the `UIImageView` has size `(0, 0)`.

**How get this effect to work on iOS, with a static `Source`?**

NOTE: The equivalent Android effect works via a handler attached to `ImageView.ViewTreeObserver.PreDraw` - at which time the size is known. So if there is an iOS equivalent event, that would be one way to solve.

---

More Details:

- The original implementation used the original image size (imageView.Image.Size) - which is available during `OnAttach`. This can be made to "work", but is not satisfactory: the glow is applied to the full size image. If the image is significantly larger than the view area, the glow becomes much too small a radius (iOS shrinks the image+glow as it renders): it does not have the desired appearance.
- `ApplyGlow` has an option to apply a tint color to the image. That tint color is different than the glow color. I mention this because it restricts the possible solutions: AFAIK, can't just set options on an image and let iOS figure out how to render it - need to explicitly resize the image and draw the resized tinted image on top of a blurred version (the glow). This code all works - *if* `imageView.Bounds.Size` (or `imageView.Frame.Size`) is available (and non-zero).
- With a breakpoint in `OnElementPropertyChanged`, I've checked to see if imageView size is known for any property that is always set. No; if no properties are dynamically set, the property changes all occur before imageView has a size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a **workaround** and I don't know if it is acceptable to you.

Add a little delay before calling `ApplyGlow();` in `OnAttached`. After the delay, you will get the `imageView.Frame.Size` or `imageView.Bounds.Size`.

```
protected override async void OnAttached()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));// it can be 0.2s,0.1s, depending on you
    ApplyGlow();
}
```

And if you have set `WidthRequest`, `HeightRequest`, you can get there without the delay:

```
private void ApplyGlow()
{
    var imageView = Control as UIImageView;
    if (imageView.Image == null)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine(imageView.Image.Size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine(imageView.Image.Size.Height);

    CoreGraphics.CGSize rect = imageView.Bounds.Size;
    CoreGraphics.CGSize rect2 = imageView.Frame.Size;

    Console.WriteLine(rect);
    Console.WriteLine(rect2);

    double width = (double)Element.GetValue(VisualElement.WidthRequestProperty);
    double height = (double)Element.GetValue(VisualElement.HeightRequestProperty);

    Console.WriteLine(width);
    Console.WriteLine(height);

    double width2 = (double)Element.GetValue(VisualElement.WidthProperty);
    double height2 = (double)Element.GetValue(VisualElement.HeightProperty);

    Console.WriteLine(width2);
    Console.WriteLine(height2);
}
```

Comment: What worked is a variation of this. If `imageView.Bounds.Size` still had 0 width or height, I delayed again, with twice the delay length. The first delay I made 50 ms. Then 100 ms, then 200 ms, then 400 ms. This way, it would usually apply the glow quickly. To avoid retrying forever, after 4 loop iterations, if Bounds still had 0 size, I applied the glow at the original image size (`imageView.Image.Size`). In that case, I didn't use `WithAspectRatio`. For my situation, `WidthRequestProperty` and `HeightRequestProperty` weren't set - but I would use those if they were.